# How to convert sequelize-cli generated migration file to typescript?

Tags: typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to convert express js sequelize-cli generated migration file from js to typescript. I have tired googling about sequelize-cli-typescript and many other tutorials but nothing seems to be working.

```
'use strict';
import { QueryInterface, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface: QueryInterface, Sequelize: typeof DataTypes) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('maps', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      icon: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface: QueryInterface, Sequelize: typeof DataTypes) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('maps');
  }
};
```

This is what i have done so far. But when i try to run command `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` it throws me an error saying "ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module"